# R - How to create/import data so the first column contains row names?

Tags: r, dataframe, pca

I'm trying to use the **logisticPCA** package with my own data. The functions of this package only work with binary data which is what i'm looking for but, the first column which usually contains the observation name or group is taken as a regular variable and doesn't work since it's non-binary data.

The package itself contains a data named **house_votes84** which, although having the first column as the group name of each observation (democrat/republican) it's not recognized as a variable and the functions of the package work perfectly. Actually, in this [website](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/logisticPCA/vignettes/logisticPCA.html):  some graphs are created by first extracting the row names of the first column:

> party = rownames(house_votes84)

I have tried many different ways to import a data.frame (mainly .csv from the notepad, with the first row, the headers, with one less name) with the first column containing the names but not being considered as a variable without success.

How do I creater or emulate this data structure in R?

```
               handicapped-infants water-project-cost-sharing
republican                   0                          1
republican                   0                          1
democrat                    NA                          1
democrat                     0                          1
democrat                     1                          1
```

Data.frame from house_votes84 simplified (row.names and 2 variables instead of 16)

Comment: Are you reading your data with `read.csv` or similar? If so, give a glance in `?read.table` to the `row.names` argument. Otherwise, say that the column containing the row names is the first and `df` is your data.frame. You can set the row names with `rownames(df)<-df[[1]]` and then eliminate the column with `df[[1]]<-NULL`.

Comment: Hi. I think i have tried this before but I still gave it a shot. `read.table` tells me that either i'm duplicating row.names when **1** is given or simply names the first column "row.names" when **NULL** is given. The other way you proposed also prompts me a message saying i'm duplicating row.names. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Load Data
library(logisticPCA)
data("house_votes84")

#Data is a list of two components:
str(house_votes84)

#Create an object with only the first two columns:
x <- house_votes84[,1:2]

#Or making it a data.frame:
df  <- as.data.frame(house_votes84[,1:2])

#Add column for party
df$party <- rownames(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Maybe I didn't explain my self properly so sorry for that. I want to create my own data in R that has the same format as house_votes84 or create it in the notepad and import it afterwards. The `str()` explained quite a bit though. Does it mean that I have to create a `data.frame` composed by two lists? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Create a file like text or csv file:

```
Party, handicapped-infants, water-project-cost-sharing
republican                   0                          1
republican                   0                          1
democrat                    NA                          1
democrat                     0                          1
democrat                     1                          1
```

Then load it:

```
df2 <- read.table("house.txt", header= T)
df3 <-read.csv("house.csv", header=T)
```

Comment: Hi!, doing that imports a data.frame with the column names being 1,2,3,4,5 and considering Party a variable which won't allow me to run any tests. I can try to put the party variable content into the row names but it will say that the row names must be unique so first row.name "republican" and second row.name "republican" will prompt an error since they are both duplicates. Thanks again!